# Find Console class in System namespace in Visual Studio references (Object browser)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

When I look in the references (Object browser) in Visual Studio, I'm not able to find the Console class.
I am able to access and use the Console class when writing a console application.

Can someone please explain why this is happening? Shouldn't it be visible in the references (object browser), when I can access it otherwise?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the Browse combobox to .NET Framework 4 then you can find it in mscorlibb.dll and then the system namespace.

You can also right click on Console and choos 'Go to definition'. There you will see in which dll/file it's decleared.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about `System.Console`. The class is defined in `mscorlib.dll` (the main .NET framework DLL). Here are the search results when I search for `Console` in the object browser in a Visual Studio .NET project:

[image: Object Browser]